# Calendar#getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) in Java 8 (java.time package)

Tags: java, time, week-number, java-time

I'm actually looking for a solution to get the years week count in Java 8, using the java.time package.

With the old methods, it was simply calling:

```
Calendar#getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

But I cant find a similar solution for java.time...

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197872/java-time-get-max-number-of-weeks-for-particular-year?

Comment: No thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Well, that's why I was looking for another solution!